# Java code explanation required, method void return type and calling method variable

Tags: java, android, return

I came across this Java code and I am a bit confused.

Following is the code

```
public ArrayList<GalleryItem> fetchItems() {
    ArrayList<GalleryItem> items = new ArrayList<GalleryItem>();

    try {
        ....

        parseItems(items, parser);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch items", ioe);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException xppe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse items", xppe);
    }
    return items;
}


void parseItems(ArrayList<GalleryItem> items, XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = parser.next();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
            ....
            item.setId(id);
            item.setCaption(caption);
            item.setUrl(smallUrl);
            items.add(item);
           ...
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}
```

What I need to know is: in above code, items is passed to `void parseitems(...)` method. As you can see the `parseitems` method has return type `void`. After parsing, the items in `fetchItems` method got the values. How is it possible? explanation please

Comment: At best, you _request_ an explanation, you don't _require_ it. Also, have you seen that there was an `items.add()`? What do you think that does?

Comment: items in both methods is local variable.

Comment: Google for "side effect".

Comment: No it isn't, unless your extract is missing some important info. `items` is the first argument to the `parseItems()` method.

Comment: Try and imagine what this method does: `void addFooToList(List<String> list) { list.add("foo"); }`

Comment: it adds a value foo to list. i dont get it how the variable in calling function got the value updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to know that in java, Objects are passed to methods by reference. This means that `parseItems` is changing the actual Object that its local reference points to.

Actually the real story is a bit more interesting: What you actually pass to the method as a parameter is the reference by value.